# Notificação de "app is running in background"

Tags: ionic, notificação

Desenvolvi aplicativo em Ionic com sucesso, mas quando o mesmo fica em background vejo uma mensagem de notificação "App is running in background".

Como retirar esta mensagem/notificação?

Answer (score 0):

Se estiver utilizando o Ionic 2, utilize a função.

```
BackgroundMode.configure({ silent: true });
```